# How do I insert yesterday's and today's dates in two table cells in html?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple document whose mwe is given in the code below. In the left and right table cells I want to have "0800 hrs LT 27 Aug.", and in the middle cell I want "1800 hrs LT 26 Aug." for example. The date will change from day to day. All the posts I have looked at do not really help me.
I will appreciate help.
Zilore Mumba

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
</style>
<script language="JavaScript">
<!-- debut
var day="";
var month="";
var myweekday="";
var year="";
mydate = new Date();
myday = mydate.getDay();
mymonth = mydate.getMonth();
myweekday= mydate.getDate();
weekday= myweekday;
myyear= mydate.getYear();
if (myyear < 1900)
myyear = 1900 + myyear ;
year = myyear ;
if(myday == 0)
....
....
// End -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<center><table class="a" id="table1" border ="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<th><h3>Minimum Temperatures:<br>0800 hrs LT</h3></th>
<th><h3>Maximum Temperatures:<br>1800 hrs LT (D-1)</h3></th>
<th><h3>Rainfall (mm):<br>0800 hrs LT</h3></th>
</tr>


<tr>
<td class="td_size" align="center"> <a target="_self" href="Obs_Output/TminR.png"><img
src="Obs_Output/TminR.png"></a></td>
<td class="td_size" align="center"> <a target="_self" href="Obs_Output/TmaxR.png"><img 
src="Obs_Output/TmaxR.png"></a></td>
<td class="td_size" align="center"> <a target="_self" href="Obs_Output/RainfallR.png"><img
src="Obs_Output/RainfallR.png"></a></td>
</tr>
</table></center>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "I want to have"? Why not just put the data in those cells?

Comment: Why is this tagged JavaScript?  Are you wanting these actions to happen on some event?  Or???  If you want JS, please update your code with the JS segement that demonstrates your best attempt at resolving this problem yourself, and clarify the action that should trigger the JS (if it's not obvious in your code), along with the point at which your code isn't working as you expect.  Otherwise, this is a coding request, not a problem with your code, and this site is not meant for free coding services.

Comment: He obviously wants the javascript to fill out the <th> innerHTML from the full context. I dont know why this gets a -1. Its a fair question but theres nothing in it to suggest his knowledge of javascript. Im disinclined to provide a solution because I get deducted if the question closes which is unfair to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ciao, by using `moment` you could set today date (`moment()`) and yesterday date (`moment().subtract(1, "days")`) in format you need (`format('D MMM')`) like this:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.17.1/moment.min.js"></script>
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html>
        <head>
        </head>
        <body>
        <center><table class="a" id="table1" border ="2" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
        <th><h3>Minimum Temperatures:<br>0800 hrs LT <div id="today"></div></h3></th>
        <th><h3>Maximum Temperatures:<br>1800 hrs LT <div id="yesterday"></div></h3></th>
        <th><h3>Rainfall (mm):<br>0800 hrs LT <div id="today"></div></h3></th>
        </tr>


        <tr>
        <td class="td_size" align="center"> <a target="_self" href="Obs_Output/TminR.png"><img
        src="Obs_Output/TminR.png"></a></td>
        <td class="td_size" align="center"> <a target="_self" href="Obs_Output/TmaxR.png"><img 
        src="Obs_Output/TmaxR.png"></a></td>
        <td class="td_size" align="center"> <a target="_self" href="Obs_Output/RainfallR.png"><img
        src="Obs_Output/RainfallR.png"></a></td>
        </tr>
        </table></center>
        </body>
        </html>
        <script> 
            (function() {
                document.querySelectorAll("#today").forEach(el => {
                   el.innerHTML = moment().format('D MMM');
                });
                document.getElementById("yesterday").innerHTML = moment().subtract(1, "days").format('D MMM');
             })();     
        </script>
```

Comment: Sorry my comments are disjointed, I would like to 1) express my sincere apologies to the other commenters. I do have a javascript to get the data which goes at the top of the document. It is too long that is why I did not mention it, but I have added a bit of it in my edit. 2) giovani where exactly do I put the three lines? I put them in the head, and they do not work. Otherwise your soluton is the perfect one I was looking for.

Comment: Just for a bit more precision, at a given time every day, shortly after 0800, the three png images are deposited in the folder by another script (bash). At that moment the dates should change. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: Ciao @ZiloreMumba, you could put the javascript lines in `<script>` tag. I have updated my answer.

Comment: Thanks very much, this responds perfectly to what I was looking for. Thank you once more @Esposito for sharing

Comment: No problem @ZiloreMumba :)

Comment: Sorry you excuse me @Esposito, I want "today", 28 Aug, to be repeated (as in the first table cell) in the third  table cell to the right. How do I do that?

Comment: @ZiloreMumba you could put div with "today" id also in third cell and, instead of call `document.getElementById("today")`, you could call `document.querySelectorAll("#today")` to get all the div with "today" id. I updated my answer.

Comment: This is really fantastic @Esposito. Thank you very much.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220624/discussion-between-zilore-mumba-and-giovanni-esposito).